# Connection to websocket via ip address refused by firefox

Tags: javascript, websocket, kaldi

I want to establish a websocket connection to my own server.

The code I tried was the following one:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://137.250.171.212:8888/ws/speech');
```

But I get an error `Firefox kann keine Verbindung zu dem Server unter ws://137.250.171.212:8888/ws/speech aufbauen.` which translates to `Firefox could not establish a connection to ws://137.250.171.212:8888/ws/speech`

The server is definetely up and running. 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the server listening for websocket connections on port 8888? Usually, the default is port 80 for unsecure and port 443 for secured SSL connections.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk thanks for the quick answer.
Yes, the server is configured to run a docker image and the server (kaldi) is listening on port 8888

Comment: Can you provide the full `docker` command or `docker-compose` file that you're using to start the Kaldi container, please?

Comment: The command is: ``sudo docker run -it -p 8888:8888 --name Kaldi_Speechrecg_German kaldi_speechrecg_german``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrongly configured target URL.
Using the correct websocket url solved the issue.